# gunicorn post_request vs flask.after_request

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I'm trying to understand the difference between [gunicorn](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#post-request) `post_request()` callback and [flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#flask.Flask.after_request) `after_request()` callback, and I'm trying to understand when to use each.

Thanks

Comment: if you use `after_request()` then you can run it with different server instead of `gunicorn`

Comment: So is there an advantage of using `post_request` at all?

Comment: I never saw if someone tried to use `post_request` but I think it can be useful if you want to use the `Gunicorn` with many `flask` - so you can write code only in one place and you don't have to repeat it in all `after_request()`. Or it can be useful if you want to use `Gunicorn` with framework which doesn't have `after_request()`.